# GOPATH и смешанные проекты

Tags: golang

Только начал осваивать Go. Согласно мануалу, GOPATH должен ссылаться на workspace, где в папке src будет храниться исходных код пакетов (и своих и чужих). У меня же основной язык PHP/C++ и я уже давно привык к структуре одна папка - один проект. Без разделения на языки: /Projects/CompanyX/ProjectNameX. Go же предлагает создать еще одну папку со своей структурой. К тому же, основной проект будет находится в одном месте, а только Go - в другом. Это просто удар по моему перфекционизуму :)
Мне удобно было бы, допустим: /Projects/freelance/site1/services/GoModule.

Вопрос. Является ли правильным при работе с Go проектом в IDE переключать GOPATH на этот конкретный workspace? Мне больше по душе один проект – один workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не является "идеологически правильным и рекомендуемым" сценарием для go-проектов в целом.

Однако если вам так удобно, а GO из коробки эту функциональность поддерживает - я не вижу причин ей не следовать.

Размещение всего проекта в одном репозитории имеет свои плюсы. Например при откате версий или изучении истории вам не нужно будет по 5 репозиториям бегать и искать что где менялось.

Либо есть еще один вариант, которым я иногда пользуюсь: физически у меня go-код лежит вместе с остальным проектом, а в GOPATH я просто из логически понятного места делаю симлинк на папку с моим кодом. Тогда и код удобно лежит и IDE, команды go работают как ожидается, без доп. обёрток/настроек.

Answer (score 0):

Все устанавливаемые пакеты скидываются как правило в

***/home/'username'/go/src/github.com***

где компилятор используя GOPATH ищет их при импортах в твоих проектах. Твои проекты размещаются тут же, ***/home/'username'/go/src/'your_project_name'*** где и происходит работа с ними. Фактически ты имеешь одно дерево для всех проектов + все пакетные зависимости в одном месте. Это крайне удобно и продуманно.

И ответ на вопрос - ты можешь переключать workspace, но будть готов к постоянному дублированию зависимых пакетов, которые импортируешь в собственную разработку, короче это путь = создание себе лишних головняков. Оно тебе надо? Риторический вопрос :)

А что один проект - один workspace= дело привычки. Поработай на Go месяцок именно с одним деревом, ты реально поймешь насколько этот концепт продуман. Ребята с Google не зря лаптем щи хлебают :))))

Comment: Это не всегда удобно. 
Например есть несколько связанных мини-проектов, за ними надо таскать разнообразные зависимости. Встроенный вендоринг помогает лишь отчасти, т.к. все зависимости будут дублироваться в каждом подпроекте и при обновлении зависимости надо вспомнить обновить эту зависимость везде, где она есть.
Если на эти связанные проекты есть отдельный GOPATH - то в репозиторий он просто складывается целиком и проблемы больше нет.

Answer (score 0):

кто то юзает docker что бы добиться изолированности workspace, лично я юзаю [maven + mvn-golang плагин](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang) что бы изолированно билдить проекты (так как тоже люблю один проект в однйо папке) и не зависеть от окружения и прописанных в окружении путей. понятие workspace как то имхо неочень удобно и неочень привычно после той же java